# Preparing a spreadsheet for pandas - some spreadsheets were opened using an older version of excel and have commas, some do not

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The spreadsheets are structured the same. The data is always there but could start on any row, my solution to this was to look for the first empty row because there is always one before the start of the data. So my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "sequence.csv"
f = open(file)

while f.readline() != '\n':
    pass

df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

f.close()
```

I have been sent some sheets recently that were opened or created using an older version of excel that added a ton of commas to the empty row for some reason. Now my code is broken i.e. the code fails to identify the first empty row. How can I identify this as an empty row, using python?

The empty row now looks like this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n
```

Instead of this:

```
\n
```

I have found there to be no predictable amount of commas. Otherwise I would have code like so:

```
while f.readline() != '\n' or ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n':
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex:

```py
import re

pattern = r",*\n"
expression = re.compile(pattern)

while expression.match(pattern, f.readline()) is None:
    pass
```

This should do the trick.

You can [see this pattern explained on Regexr](https://regexr.com/6qrv3).